# Local IP address in IP header information

Tags: ip

When I see my IP on the internet it says 64.xxx.xxx.xxx (class A). So routing of my packet has 64.xxx.xxx.xxx as the source address in the header. May be after all the subnetting the receive packet comes to my home router, how does the home router know which private IP to send the received packets to? my private ip is 192.168.1.4 is that somehow included in the sent and received packets that my home router extracts? where exactly is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NAT-net work address translation and in specific NAPT-network address and port translation is what you are looking for. The router maintains the list of ports through which a packet is sent along with the private ip or something similar in a translation table.

Comment: By port do u mean the tcp/udp port? but what if my roommate is using another appliation at the same port?... I know tcp/udp packets contain the port number but does the router put that info in the IP header or options?.

Comment: each local machine is assigned a private IP by the router. This along with the port number is unique enough to be mapped onto a single public IP. For your second question-The NAPT occurs in the tcp/udp level.so the tcp header is modified by the router.think of it as a proxy

Answer (score 1):

Your router does NAT, which isn't on IP level. It's on a higher level, your router behaves as a TCP Proxy.